# How I can write code in 2 lines in the Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

colleagues!

Sometimes I have a very long string in the code, e.g. more than 200 symbols in a string.

Could I carry some trail to the new line in the Robot Framework code?

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the built-in keyword [Catenate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Catenate) and the line continuation syntax (the triple dots `...`)

```
${long var}=    Catenate    This is a long string
                    ...     that will be concatenated

# you can combine multiple Catenate calls, for formatting clarity:
${long var}=    Catenate   ${long var}, and it continues on
                    ...     multiple lines.
```

By default the different portions will be concatenated with a space, you can change that with the `SEPARATOR` argument (the case matters).

Comment: Actually, a have a lot of arguments and long selectors. But your solution with `...` is worked and suitable for me. Thank you!

Comment: Well you can add lines with `...` however times you need, I used just one in the example because typing on mobile. And, you can combine multiple `Catenate` statements passing in the variable as first argument for formatting clarity; updated the answer with that.