# Robot framework not allowing me to break message across multiple lines

Tags: robotframework

I've got the following code and it won't allow me to break my message over multiple lines. I've looked at over a dozen stack exchange questions but none of them work.

```
Should Be Equal As Integers    ${ans}    0      msg=Failed stuff, the accepted value did not match. Expected value \n
...     was between max and min, returned value is below this
```

It is giving me the error

> Keyword 'BuiltIn.Should Be Equal As Integers' got positional argument after named arguments.
> I've looked at the following links but they don't work

- [How I can write code in 2 lines in the Robot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50746052/how-i-can-write-code-in-2-lines-in-the-robot-framework)
- [Robot framework not allowing me to print over multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68559593/robot-framework-not-allowing-me-to-print-over-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `catenate`:

```
${ans} =       Convert To Integer    1
${message} =   Catenate    Failed stuff, the accepted value did not match. Expected value \n
...                        was between max and min, returned value is below this

Should Be Equal As Integers    ${ans}    0      msg=${message}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the error message on single line and you can Add `${\n}` at the end of the string to get a newline character.
I think, you are using a kw which has positional argument it may not allow using real new line using `...`
However, you can use Catenate keyword with SEPARATOR=\n as below:

```
${str3} =   Catenate    SEPARATOR=\n    line1 text
...    line2 text
```